# How to write the square of a determinant or a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, determinant

$${\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{vmatrix}}^2=(-2)^2\tag{1}$$

$${\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}}^2=\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 10\\
15 & 22
\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

Can I write the square of matrices and determinants in the above way?

Comment: Yes, you surely can.

Comment: Now a follow-up question: does one notate the determinant's absolute value as
$\begin{vmatrix}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{vmatrix}}\end{vmatrix}$ or $\begin{vmatrix}\det{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}}\end{vmatrix}\;?$

Comment: @ryang The latter is is far better: the former is used as a notation for indicating a matrix as well.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic I'm not sure that the former indicates a matrix, but it certainly looks to me like a [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), so yes, the latter is when I will switch to writing "det A".

Comment: another possibility is $\text{abs} \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{vmatrix}$